# Continue block command

Tags: r

I try to run this code:

```
library (stackr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1144035, 58936751))
for (j in 1:2) {
  tryCatch({
  reputation_history <- stack_users(df$id[j], "reputation-history")


  }, error = function( err ) {
    print(paste( "Error:", err ))

  })}
```

However I receive this error:

> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8. [1] "Error: Error: lexical
>   error: invalid char in json text.\n Too\n (right here) ------^\n\n"

I use the try and catch to make the code continue working. However it doesn't work. Is there any possibility to keep it working and keep the id which had the error?

Comment: I run your code but couldn't reproduce your errors.

Comment: @TeeKea thank you please take a look if you want to reproduce the simple version of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936751/encoding-calling-api-format

Comment: It works fine on my side. The first `id` has encoding errors but is skipped by the `tryCatch` and the second one is parsed correctly.